# how to find characters in a string and then remove them if they match a particular character?

Tags: c++11

/* I have to find character and remove them, based on the character it has to go inside the if/else if condition. I am facing difficulty in getting inside the else if condition */

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int fut = 0, spd =0;
    std::string symbol = "PGSh/d TWOGK h/d"; //it will contain either 'h/d' or '/'

    std::string str = "h/d";
    std::string str1 = "/";
if(symbol.find(str))   //if it finds "h/d" then it belongs to future
{
    ++fut;    //even one count is enough
    boost::erase_all(symbol, "h/d");
    std::cout<<"Future Instrument "<<std::endl;
}
else if(symbol.find(str1)) //if it finds "/" then it belongs to spread
{
    ++spd;    //even one count is enough
    boost::erase_all(symbol, "//");
    std::cout<<"Spread Instrument "<<std::endl;
}
boost::erase_all(symbol, " ");
boost::to_upper(symbol);
std::cout<<symbol<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am facing difficulty in getting inside the else if condition"? Your first `if` will be true, so by definition you will never take the `else if` branch.

Comment: yes, but what if symbol has "PGS/ TWOGK /" then also it is going inside if branch, I want to know, is there any way where it matches the entire str/str1 not just a part of it.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you want, but I think [regular expression search](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) is what you are after?  Something like [`"\B/\B"`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) would match `"PGSx/y"` but not  `"PGSx/"`or  `"PGS /"`. Please describe further what patterns you wish to find and which you wish to reject.

Comment: I want, if in the symbol there is "h/d" then it should go to the if case(future instrument) and if in the symbol there is "/" then it should go to the else if case. which is not happening in the code provided above.

Comment: `symbol.find(str)` returns an index at which the substring is found, or `string::npos` if it's not found. Your `if` condition will be true except in one case - when the substring is found at index 0. You likely want `if(symbol.find(str) != std::string::npos)...`

Comment: IgorTandetnik - thank you so much, it works!! :)